# Creating POJO for JSON where child nodes are dynamic

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a JSON file which looks like this. I am going to receive this JSON as a response for an API:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "SUCCESS",
    "value": {
        "APP": {
            "option1": false,
            "option2": false
        },
        "DESKTOP": {
            "multiValued": true,
            "lob": true
        },
        "TestSomeLob": {
            "multiValued": true,
            "lob": true
        }
    }
}
```

The nodes inside the value node can increase or decrease based upon the state of the application. I am trying to create pojo for the above mentioned response so that I can get the list of values. Can anybody help me in creating the pojos for the same?

Comment: How about declaring `value` as `Map<String, Map<String, Boolean>>`? (unless `Map<String, Boolean>` can be replaced with an existing bean class)

Comment: Can we create a POJO for value in Map<String, Map<String, Boolean>> format?

Comment: If you json always remains same,you can create pojo out of your json here - http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Do you have the possibility to manage the child nodes in a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of

1. jsonanygetter (http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-annotations.html#jsonanygetter)
2. jsonanysetter (http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-annotations.html#jsonanysetter)
3. jsoncreator (http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-annotations.html#jsoncreator)

   ```
   public class POJONAME_TO_BE_REPLACED{

       // Two mandatory properties
       protected final boolean success;
       protected final String message;

       // Other flexible properties
       protected Map<String,Object> otherProps = new HashMap<String,Object>();

       @JsonCreator
       public POJONAME_TO_BE_REPLACED(@JsonProperty("success") boolean success, @JsonProperty("message") String message)
       {
           this.success = success;
           this.message = message;
       }

       public boolean getSuccess() { return success; }
       public String getMessage() { return message; }

       public Object get(String propName) {
           return otherProps.get(propName);
       }

       @JsonAnyGetter
       public Map<String,Object> any() {
           return otherProps;
       }

       @JsonAnySetter
       public void set(String propName, Object value) {
           otherProps.put(propName, value);
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer Shubhankar. Please upvote it if it helped.